# Есть ли у data: URI ограничения?

Tags: html, url, uri

Если есть, то какой длиной (весом) ограничены? Само собой, что интересуют последние версии браузеров.

Comment: Везде по-разному.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [пункте 3.2.1 спецификации](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) говорится, что нет ограничений и серверы должны уметь работать с любой длиной запроса. Если же не могут обработать, то возвращать ошибку 414 (Request-URI Too Long):

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of
> a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they
> serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they
> provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server
> SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer
> than the server can handle (see section 10.4.15).

В обновлённой версии спецификации [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) говорится про 8k:

> Various ad hoc limitations on request-line length are found in
> practice.  It is RECOMMENDED that all HTTP senders and recipients
> support, at a minimum, request-line lengths of 8000 octets.

Это то, что говорит спецификация. По факту же...

Можно посмотреть [это](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) исследование.

Или почитать [это](http://wiert.me/2010/04/20/maximum-url-lengths/):

- Internet Explorer 4-9 максимум 2083. В новых версиях, видимо тоже, если верить [msdn](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/208427).
- Firefox 64k (больше этого не отображается в адресной строке в браузере, но сами запросы с длиной ссылки большей 64к вроде работают).
- В Chrome и Safari сложно сказать.

Comment: Если верить [этому](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff919564%28v=office.14%29.aspx), то  `However, in Internet Explorer 7, under certain circumstances, the effective URL length limitation is 1024 UTF-8 characters`

Comment: Даже сохраню себе :-)

Comment: @avp 1024 - эффективный размер. Там же про максимальный размер написано `Both Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8 have a maximum URL length of 2,083 UTF-8 characters`

Comment: Да, написано, а в чем разница -- нет. Непонятно. Также не очень понятно, что они подразумевают под `UTF-8 characters`. Т.о. осторожная оценка -- 1024.

Answer (score 3):

Когда попытался вывести 60-мегабайтный файл через `data:` URI, FireFox дико затормозил. Поэтому стал использовать [`blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob), с которым сбор и скачивание файла весом в десятки Мб в JS происходит легко и непринуждённо.

Comment: Та не, то перебор. Мне до 100 килобайт. Больше не надо.

Answer (score 3):

Можно поместить такое в адресную строку (в IE не работает) и посмотреть, что получится:

```
data:text/html,<!doctype html><script>"*";document.write("<title>"+location.href.length+"</title>");setTimeout('location.href=location.href.replace("*","-*")')</script>
```

Хром что-то долго считал - надоело, поменял на такое:

```
data:text/html,<!doctype html><script>"-";document.write("<title>"+location.href.length+"</title>");setTimeout('location.href=location.href.replace(/-/g,"--")')</script>
```

Получилось 131237 символов.

Потом подумал, понял, что там было не удвоение, и поправил:

```
data:text/html,<!doctype html><script>"0";document.write("<title>"+location.href.length+"</title>");setTimeout('location.href=location.href.replace(/\\d/g,"$&$&")')</script>
```

Досчиталось до 33554604, после чего вылезло сообщение, что страница не ответчает.

Answer (score 2):

Могу ошибаться, но вроде 4К, как и любые другие url.